# Блокирует ли ReentrantLock весь объект или только часть кода?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня задача заблокировать объект если в него зашел хотя-бы один поток. Я хочу использовать `ReentrantLock` для этого.

И есть два метода которые под этим локом:

```
private final Lock monitor = new ReentrantLock();

public boolean update(final K idKey, final V newValue) {
    this.monitor.lock();
    try {
        // что-то там...
    } finally {
        this.monitor.unlock();
    }
}

public boolean add(final K idKey, final V newValue) {
    this.monitor.lock();
    try {
        // что-то там...
    } finally {
        this.monitor.unlock();
    }
}
```

Вопрос: если есть два потока, и поток номер 1 уже зашел в метод `update`и что-то там делает, а поток номер 2 хочет зайти в это время в метод `add`, то потоку номер 2 придется ждать пока поток номер 1 не закончит? Или блокировано будет только тело метода `update`?

Comment: Поток 2 остановится на строке `this.monitor.lock();` и будет там стоять до тех пор, пока поток 1 не вызовет `this.monitor.unlock();`. В каких это методах будет происходить - неважно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReentrantLock` не блокирует ничего кроме потока, который вызвал `lock()` (если он занят другим потоком).

В вашем случае **поток 2** будет заблокирован до тех пор, пока **поток 1** не вызовет `unlock()`. При этом **поток 1** может вызвать `lock()` многократно и он не будет блокироваться.